# Hue Pyspark connector using Livy - Increate spark driver memory for interactive sessions

Tags: pyspark, hue, livy, cdp, cloudera-cdp

We are using CDP private cloud 7.1.7 and have configured Hue connector for pyspark using livy. By default I can see the driver launches with 1GB memory and I need to increase this as some of the code we are running is failing due to OOM errors for driver container. I tried setting the default spark driver memory to a higher value under spark config which works fine with spark-submit or directly using livy api. But When I launch a livy session via Hue its still launching with 1gb.

Any idea how I can apply this via Hue?

Thanks,
Sajin

I tried setting the default spark driver memory to a higher value under spark config which works fine with spark-submit or directly using livy api. But When I launch a pyspark session via Hue its still launching with 1gb.